# text is overlapping to next table column

Tags: html, css

I have a table below:

```
    <table id="tableqanda" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="6%" class="noofanswers">Number of Answers</th>
        <th width="5%" class="answer">Answer</th>
        <th width="6%" class="noofreplies">Number of Replies</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
    <div id="tableqanda_onthefly_container">
    <table id="tableqanda_onthefly" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <?php
          foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {
        echo '<tr class="tableqandarow">'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td width="6%" class="noofanswers">'.htmlspecialchars($arrNoofAnswers[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td width="5%" class="answers">'.htmlspecialchars($arrAnswer[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td width="6%" class="noofreplies">'.htmlspecialchars($arrReplyType[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL; 
        echo '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
        }
?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

The table is a scrolling table with fixed headers. But this is not the issue. The issue I have is with the answer column, If you look at the screen shot below, you can see for the first row under the `Answer` column, the answers are overlapping the column next to it, rather than displaying the rest of the content underneath. Why is this happening?

Below is screenshot:

[image]

Below is the CSS:

```
#tableqanda_onthefly_container
{
    width:100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height:500px;
}

#tableqanda_onthefly
{
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    clear:both;
}

#tableqanda_onthefly td
{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

#tableqanda, #tableqanda_onthefly{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}       

#tableqanda{
    width:100%;
    margin-left:0;
    float:left;
}

#tableqanda td { 
    vertical-align: middle;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

#tableqanda th{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    text-align:center;
}

.tableqandarow{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of suggestions:
1. Don't try to put table headers and detail rows into two different tables. I know that is not something you asked but a suggestions.
2. You want to change the CSS for the table so it's not a fix layout.

```
#tableqanda, #tableqanda_onthefly{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

your data is bigger than allocated space. You can also use wrap to wrap the text to make sure it does not go out of the layout.

Comment: Thank you, yeah the reason I have two tables is for the fixed headers when scrolling the table. Thanks again